# How to use CSS selector to identify an object inside a span class

Tags: css

I need to identify an object using CSS selector, but  I am facing a problem

This is the web element I am trying to identify:

```
<span class="tag-bold">TRF100002</span>
```

How to translate this line into CSS selector?

Comment: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) is a reference guide to CSS selectors. See if that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

this selector will select all `span` elements with class `tag-bold`

```
span.tag-bold
```

If you have more of these and you want to select only some you will have to give them IDs.

Java can handle only limited html subset in its components. I tested this selector only in `JLabel` and `JTextPane` (works in both).

Comment: I need to select an specific item, I want to know the CSS path so I can replace the value TRF100002 and add a variable instead

Comment: @PattyAyala Wait, wasn't this question about displaying html text inside Java component? Is your html displayed in a real internet browser?